# Multiple state update in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [criteria, setCriteria] = useState({});

  const handleCriteriaChange = (values) => {
    // setCriteria(prevCriteria => ({
    //   ...prevCriteria,
    //   ...values
    // }))
    setCriteria({
      ...criteria,
      ...values
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleCriteriaChange({
        courses: ["calculus", "psychology"]
      });
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      handleCriteriaChange({
        type: "manual"
      });
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      handleCriteriaChange({
        termLengths: [14, 7]
      });
    }, 10000);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  console.log({ criteria: JSON.stringify(criteria) });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {JSON.stringify(criteria)}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've added a logic to update state object with different keys in 5 seconds gap between each update. And I was expecting all key values appear in the state object, but only the last state update is displaying. Why I can't get all the added key: values? Even if there's a state batching they are updating state with different keys.

Comment: You have a stale reference to your state in `handleCriteriaChange `, overriding the state with old state.

Comment: How does the state is stale in `handleCriteriaChange`?

Comment: Your `useEffect` only has a reference to the first `handleCriteriaChange` that was created, inside of that is a stale reference to the first state.

Answer (score 0):

the issue with your update state function `handleCriteriaChange`. variable `criteria` is empty in `useEffect` function and when you use it or assign it. you have to use the previous state value while updating the state.

```
import React from 'react';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [criteria, setCriteria] = useState({});

  const handleCriteriaChange = (values) => {
   
    setCriteria(prev=> ({
      ...prev,
      ...values,
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleCriteriaChange({
        courses: ['calculus', 'psychology'],
      });
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      handleCriteriaChange({
        type: 'manual',
      });
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      handleCriteriaChange({
        termLengths: [14, 7],
      });
    }, 10000);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  console.log({ criteria: JSON.stringify(criteria) });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {JSON.stringify(criteria)}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. Excellent answer....